# C# New Project change default lines project.cs

Tags: c#

i`m new to Programming and new to c# & visual studio.

i started to resolve some exercises and save the projects to a specified folder. but every time i want to make another exercise i  open a new project and name it exNumber. The vs opens the project.cs with default main().

How can i change the lines of default project.cs to be like this:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ex2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Write a C# Sharp program to that takes three numbers(x,y,z) as input and print the output of (x+y)·z and x·y + y·z.");  // To do 
            Console.WriteLine("=================================================================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("RESULT:");
            Console.WriteLine("=================================================================================================");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See this: [How to Create Project Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [Project Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx)

1. Create project and set up all the code you want to be in your template.
2. File -> Export Template -> Project Template -> Follow Dialogs -> Finish
3. When you need to create a new project select your new template instead of what you're usually choosing such as "Console Application".